# Outline on ui:button when press

Tags: lightning, css, lightning-design-system

Hi I try set color of my ui:button border on click to none or transparent. 
This is part of my code. 
my aura:

```
<ui:button  class="btn btn-image"/>
```

css

```
.THIS .btn:focus {
        outline-color: transparent !important;
    }
    .THIS .btn-image {
         background: url(/resource/btn) no-repeat;
         border: transparent;
         height: 150px;
         width: 150px;
   }
```

OR

```
    .THIS .btn:focus {
        outline: none !important;
    }
    .THIS .btn-image {
         background: url(/resource/btn) no-repeat;
         border: transparent;
         height: 150px;
         width: 150px;
   }
```

Comment: can you provide more details on problem that you are facing. e.g component code snippet

Comment: I try use circle image with transparent background as ui:button but when I click on it I have blue border around.

Comment: Hi, updated my answer to completely remove the blue border on focus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

It looks like you are using `extends="force:slds"` in your app, as you don't get a blue border if you use a `ui:button` without it.

This completely turns off the blue:

```
.THIS .btn-image {
    background: red no-repeat;
    border: transparent;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}

.THIS .slds-button:hover {
    background: red no-repeat;
    outline-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.THIS .slds-button:focus {
    background: red no-repeat;
    outline-color: transparent ;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```